# Integrating a Fine-Tuned Chatbot Using LLMs into a Website - Seeking Guidance and Resources

Tags: python, frontend, backend, chatbot, openai-api

Body:

The internet is filled with tutorials on how to fine-tune a chatbot using various LLMs like ChatGPT, LLAMA 2, etc., and I have successfully managed to build a custom chatbot with a knowledge base in Python. However, I've hit a roadblock when it comes to deploying the chatbot and integrating it into my website for user interaction.

Therefore, I'm reaching out to the community with the following requests:

**Integration Experience:** If you have experience with this, could you share your insights on how to integrate a fine-tuned chatbot into a website? Specific tools, frameworks, or best practices would be incredibly helpful.

**Comprehensive Guides**: If there are any tutorials, guides, or blog posts detailing this process, especially those catering to the LLMs mentioned, please share them. It would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and insights.

Comment: You could use Dialogflow for the chatbot interface (Google Cloud), and make requests to the fine tuned LLM via webhook. Take a look: https://medium.com/@rubenszimbres/search-of-brazilian-laws-using-dialogflow-cx-and-matching-engine-b384c745c77e